# Find the specific values for K

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to solve the following exercise:

Given the following system of linear equations:
$\begin{cases}-4x + 3y = 2\\ 5x - 4y = 0  \\ 2x-y = k\end{cases}$

Find the values for k that allow for a unique solution, no solutions, infinitely many solutions.

So I tried to find the values of X and Y:

$\begin{cases}-4x + 3y = 2\\ 5x - 4y = 0 \end{cases}$

I managed to arrive at $x = - 8$ and $y  = -10$

But I'm stuck now, how do I find these conditions on $k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x=-8$ and $y=-10$ is a solution of the first two equations. The system has a solution

$\iff 2(-8)-(-10)=k \iff k=-6$.

Conclusion: the system has a unique solution $ \iff k=-6$, it has no solution $ \iff k \ne -6$, infinitely many solutions are not possible.